# Uncaught error expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply just trying to place a text file into a variable fileDom to have inside my web application.  Right now I am not parsing anything, just storing the data.

My html is a placeholder for later use, but is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css/reader.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/reader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my script is:

```
var HTML_FILE_URL = 'http://localhost/feed.txt';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data) {
        var fileDom = $(data);
            console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

I created a XAMPP that runs holds the txt file and the scripting file to avoid technical request security measurements for development.

Anyway, the syntax error doesn't recognize the expression so the log shows:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression
```

All the content in my txt file, no quotes, just the string itself as intended 
and the line error points me to the API and this line:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Simple solution I'm sure, but I can't get around to parsing and storing the lines from the file until I get this (probably really silly solution) figured out.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the data into `fileDom`, instead of this...

```
var fileDom = $(data);
```

do this:

```
var fileDom = data;
```

You cannot pass arbitrary strings to `$`. The `$` function expects either selectors or HTML fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish the task you have to read the context of the text the  via the FileReader() method which is the same as XMLHttpRequest  then you will need to read that data as text using readAsText().....the contents of the result are then stored in by calling event.target.result

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
        var contents = event.target.result;
        console.log("File contents: " + contents);
};

      reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("File could not be read! Code " +                                
             event.target.error.code);
       };

reader.readAsText(file);
```